# Unique combinations of partitioned rows

Tags: sql, unique, rows, combinations

I am trying to validate some data relating to trips made by certain vehicles.

The trip data is of the form

```
Vehicle   Trip    Place_Name
      1      1         ATown
      1      2         BTown
      1      3         ATown
      2      1         ATown
      2      2         CTown
```

This table links to information regarding each place. Unfortunately, some of the stated places are not unique ie there may be more than one place named ATown.

So the place data is of the form

```
Place_ID   Place_Name  Co-ordinates
       1        ATown     Lat1,Lng1
       2        ATown     Lat2,Lng2
       3        ATown     Lat3,Lng3
       4        BTown     Lat4,Lng4
       5        BTown     Lat5,Lng5
       6        CTown     Lat6,Lng6
```

So there are three places names Atown, two places named BTown and only one place named CTown.

If I join the two tables

```
select T.Vehicle , T.Trip , P.Place_ID , P.Place_Name
from Trips as T
left join
Places as P
on T.Place_Name = T.Place_Name
```

I get

```
T.Vehicle   T.Trip  P.Place_ID  P.Place_Name
      1          1           1         ATown
      1          1           2         ATown
      1          1           3         ATown
      1          2           4         BTown
      1          2           5         BTown
      1          3           1         ATown
      1          3           2         ATown
      1          3           3         ATown
      2          1           1         ATown
      2          1           2         ATown
      2          1           3         ATown
      2          2           6         CTown
```

What I'm trying to get is a set of unique place combinations for each vehicle

```
Vehicle Possibility Trip Place_Name Place_ID
      1           1    1      ATown        1
      1           1    2      BTown        4
      1           1    3      ATown        1
      1           2    1      ATown        2
      1           2    2      BTown        4
      1           2    1      ATown        1
      1           3    1      ATown        3
      1           3    2      BTown        4
      1           3    3      ATown        1
      1           4    1      ATown        1
      1           4    2      BTown        5
      1           4    3      ATown        1
      1           5    1      ATown        2
      1           5    2      BTown        5
      1           5    3      ATown        1
      1           6    1      ATown        3
      1           6    2      BTown        5
      1           6    3      ATown        1
      1           7    1      ATown        1
      1           7    2      BTown        4
      1           7    3      ATown        3
      1           8    1      ATown        2
      1           8    2      BTown        4
      1           8    3      ATown        3
      1           9    1      ATown        3
      1           9    2      BTown        4
      1           9    3      ATown        3
```

Vehicle 1 should end up with 18 possible routes and vehicle 2 with 3. The number of trips each vehicle makes varies as does the number of towns with the same name.

Once I have the place combinations, I can then use the co-ordinates to plot routes for each vehicle and work out the start to end distance. I will then use this to validate other distance information.

I'm struggling to work out where to start on constructing a SQL query that would produce the results I need.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your join is correct . . . but you then need to join again to get the second leg:

```
select stop1.Vehicle, stop1.Trip,
       stop1.Place_Name as Place_Name1, stop2.Place_Name as Place_Name2,
       stop1.Place_id as PlaceId1, stop2.Place_id as Palce_Id2
from (select T.Vehicle, T.Trip, P.Place_ID, P.Place_Name
      from Trips as T left join
           Places as P
           on T.Place_Name = T.Place_Name
     ) stop1 join
     (select T.Vehicle, T.Trip, P.Place_ID, P.Place_Name
      from Trips as T left join
           Places as P
           on T.Place_Name = T.Place_Name
     ) stop2
     on stop1.Vehicle = stop2.Vehicle and
        stop1.trip = stop2.trip + 1;
```

I'm not sure what "possibility" represents.  If you want to enumerate these somehow, then that depends on the database.  The above is standard SQL and should work for most databases.